# How to perform pagination in @get endpoint

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopbackjs, loopback4

In case I've huge records (millions) in my table; How can I paginate them in `GET` request?

LoopBack 4 [official control example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/6a228264f3bb67af53fd74ebbf9439cab44fa286/examples/todo-list/src/controllers/todo-list.controller.ts#L69) doesn't emulate this case. I couldn't find any reference for a real case solution (they mentioned an example for the pagination in [skip filter](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Skip-filter.html) but it's not mentioning how to use it with repository methods ex. `find()`).

Do you've any example or snippet for that case?

**EDIT** (I saw someone voted to close this question): The main reason of this question is preventing the front-end developer to make any mistake by calling a huge query may impact on server performance (in case she/he forget to use `skip` & `limit` filters).

Answer (score 0):

One way to emulate pagination is to enforce a `limit` filter.

LoopBack 4 can handle this for you with [Model scopes](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html#scope) ([permalink](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/ea107f412f837fd3f07e52df1667f5bd11517616/docs/site/Model.md#scope)):

```js
@model({
  settings: {
    scope: {
      limit: 50,
    },
  },
})
class MyModel extends Entity {/* ... */}
```

---

To apply the scope to only a select few endpoints, the `Controller` can modify the filter before passing it to the Repository function:

```js
class MyController {
  @get('/')
  async find(
    @param.filter(MyModel) filter?: Filter<MyModel>
  ): Promise<MyModel[]> {
    const sanitizedFilter = Object.assign(filter, {limit: 50});
    return this.myRepository.find(sanitizedFilter);
  }
}
```

---

Both examples perform the same thing: Enforce a limit on the maximum number of items that can be queried in one request.

To get the next 50 items, the API consumer can add a `skip` filter to their query to get the next "page":

```
?filter={skip: 50}
```

Comment: Awesome @rifa-achrinza
Can I apply a similar solution at repository level?
I try to keep my models without any modification (because I use `lb4 discover`). The simple modifications apply on controllers level and the heavy ones in repository level.

Comment: I tried to apply a filter in repository level but it didn't affect on the result!
`const filter = {
      where: {
        color: colorStr,
      },
      include: [{
        relation: 'todos',
        limit: 20,
      }],
    }
`